# Webpack CommonsChunkPlugin not works as expected

Tags: javascript, webpack

As [docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/optimization.html#multi-page-app) says:

> If your entry chunks have some modules in common, there is a cool plugin for this. The CommonsChunkPlugin identifies common modules and put them into a commons chunk.

My webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        p1: "./page1",
        p2: "./page2",
        p3: "./page3"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].entry.js",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "/dist/",
        chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('commons.chunk.js'),
    ]
}
```

page1.js: `require(['jquery', 'lodash'], function($) { /* page 1 */ });`

page2.js: `require(['jquery', 'svgjs'], function($) { /* page 2 */ });`

page3.js: `require(['jquery', 'scriptjs'], function($) { /* page 3 */ });`

What I expect from `webpack --progress --colors   --display-chunks` is the that `commons.chunk.js` will contain `jquery` code, but ist not. `commons.chunk.js` contains only initial webpack stuff. And each page chunk contains `jquery` code.

Webpack output:

```
Hash: b931a47382d3148a8b55  
Version: webpack 1.12.14
Time: 696ms
           Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
     p1.entry.js  333 bytes    0, 6  [emitted]  p1
      1.chunk.js     761 kB    1, 6  [emitted]  
     p2.entry.js  333 bytes    2, 6  [emitted]  p2
      3.chunk.js     389 kB    3, 6  [emitted]  
     p3.entry.js  333 bytes    4, 6  [emitted]  p3
      5.chunk.js     271 kB    5, 6  [emitted]  
commons.chunk.js    3.52 kB       6  [emitted]  commons.chunk.js
chunk    {0} p1.entry.js (p1) 61 bytes {6} [rendered]
    [0] ./page1.js 61 bytes {0} [built]
chunk    {1} 1.chunk.js 738 kB {0} [rendered]
     + 3 hidden modules
chunk    {2} p2.entry.js (p2) 60 bytes {6} [rendered]
    [0] ./page2.js 60 bytes {2} [built]
chunk    {3} 3.chunk.js 376 kB {2} [rendered]
     + 2 hidden modules
chunk    {4} p3.entry.js (p3) 63 bytes {6} [rendered]
    [0] ./page3.js 63 bytes {4} [built]
chunk    {5} 5.chunk.js 262 kB {4} [rendered]
     + 2 hidden modules
chunk    {6} commons.chunk.js (commons.chunk.js) 0 bytes [rendered]
```

Am I doing it wrong? Or I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after restless night I found solution. `require()` is [split point](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#amd-require). And if I want to `CommonsChunkPlugin magic` to work, I should `define` pages:

page1.js: `define(['jquery', 'lodash'], function($) { /* page 1 */ });`

page2.js: `define(['jquery', 'svgjs'], function($) { /* page 2 */ });`

page3.js: `define(['jquery', 'scriptjs'], function($) { /* page 3 */ });`

In my case it is better move `jquery` to explicitly defined [vendor](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#2-explicit-vendor-chunk) chunk.